# FormData is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

```
var formdata = new FormData();
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
  formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
}
```

`FormData` is not working in Internet Explore when i try to post files. I need to upload files in `IE` only by using `FormData`.

Can any one point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should always mention what version of IE you are using.

Answer (score 1):

FormData is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and below: http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata . There are file-upload modules that get around this problem by using iframes: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload